# Evaluate expression stored in Varchar Column directly in the "select" statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table named `PriceDetails` with three columns 
`"price","discount formula" and "finalprice"`. I have to calculate final price based on `"Price" and "discount formula"` columns.

My table looks like this,

```
Price   DiscountFormulae
100     100*(3/100)
200     200*(1.1/100)+200*(5/100)
300     300*(1/100)+300*(3/100)+300*(2/100)
400     400*(7/100)+400*(6.6/100)+400*(5.5/100)+400*(4/100)
```

I want to calculate final price. The formula would be `"Price"-"DiscountFormulae"`

for example

100 - (100*(3/100)) =97

My Expected Output would be

```
Price   DiscountFormulae FinalPrice
100     100*(3/100)         97

Note: My DiscountFormulae Column is Varchar(1000)
```

How do I get this. Please help me.

Comment: Storing a calculation in a text column is not a great design and means that you open yourself up to runtime errors. How about you create a DiscountAmount column (Numeric) and add the result of your calculation into the column i.e. 3 in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very good solution, but it shows, how difficult is it:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (Price int, DiscountFormula Varchar(1000))
INSERT INTO #temp 
(#temp.Price, #temp.DiscountFormula)
VALUES
(100,'100.0*(3.0/100)'),
(200,'200.0*(1.1/100)+200*(5.0/100)'),
(300,'300.0*(1.0/100)+300*(3.0/100)+300*(2.0/100)'),
(400,'400.0*(7.0/100)+400*(6.6/100)+400*(5.5/100)+400*(4.0/100)')

DECLARE @price int

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT t.Price FROM #temp AS t
OPEN cur
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @price
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN

    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX) = N'
    SELECT 
        t.Price,
        t.DiscountFormula,
        ' + (SELECT TOP 1 DiscountFormula FROM #Temp WHERE Price = @price) + N' as Value
    FROM #temp AS t
    WHERE Price = ' +CONVERT(nvarchar(max),@price)

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @price
END

CLOSE cur

DROP TABLE #temp
```

By the way, use float values in formula.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I know how to do this in a loop. Is any way to prepare a single dynamic select without loop.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I will vote up. Please tell me any other set based approach apart from loop.

Comment: @StackUser i'm afraid, I don't know a better way

Comment: I selected your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in a stored procedure, like:

But dynamic SQL, like `exec` or `sp_executesql`, is not allowed in user defined functions.

```
DECLARE @calc varchar(max)
SET @calc = '100*(3/100)'

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @result float
SET @sql = N'SET @result = ' + @calc
exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@result float output', @result out
SELECT @result
```

Comment: I know this approach. I have to do the same for each and every row inside the stored procedure. Is any way to directly do this in select statement itself

Comment: @StackUser You cant do it in single select statement. You have to use SP for it